# ループ終了後に、結果を最後にまとめて取得したい

Tags: python

---

**質問内容が分かりづらかったので、コードや欲しい結果を具体的に書きます**
・再帰と勘違いしていたので、タイトルも変更しました

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・[このリンク先にあるコード](https://github.com/REMitchell/python-scraping/blob/master/chapter3/1-getWikiLinks.py)結果を、Bottleを使用してWeb画面上に表示したい

**試したこと**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import random
import re
from bottle import route, view

random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

def getLinks(articleUrl):
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org"+articleUrl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return bsObj.find("div", {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))

@route('/')
@view("test_template")
def test():
    links = getLinks("/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
    results = []
    while len(links) > 0:
        newArticle = links[random.randint(0, len(links)-1)].attrs["href"]
        results.append(newArticle)
        links = getLinks(newArticle)
        dict(results=results)
```

・画面表示結果例

> ['/wiki/Randy_Quaid']

・上記はループ時にテンプレートへ渡しているので、ループ終了後に結果をまとめてテンプレートへ渡したいと思い、下記へ変更したら無限ループに陥ったのですがナゼでしょうか？

```
     while len(links) > 0:
         newArticle = links[random.randint(0, len(links)-1)].attrs["href"]
         results.append(newArticle)
         links = getLinks(newArticle)
     dict(results=results)
```

・最終的に欲しい結果のイメージ(あくまでも想定の範囲です)

> ['/wiki/Richard_Chamberlain','/wiki/Richard_Chamberlain']

---

**以下当初質問した内容**

・下記コードで、ループ最中に随時出力するわけではなく、ループ終了後にまとめて取得したい場合はどうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
def getHoge(p):
    return 処理

res = getHoge("文字列")

def hoge():
    while len(res) > 0:
        str = 処理
        print(str)
        links = getHoge(str)

hoge()
```

---

・文字列で構成されたオブジェクトで取得？
※そもそも「どういう形式で取得できるか」自体、良く分かっていません

・試したけれどもうまく動作しない(無限ループ？)コード

```
def getHoge(p):
    return 処理

res = getHoge("文字列")

result = ['1'] #変数定義。代入しないと定義できないと書いてあったので取り敢えず適当に'1'を代入しました
def hoge():
    global result
    while len(res) > 0:
        str = 処理
        print(str)
        result.append(str)
        links = getHoge(str)
    retuen result #ここで取得したい
hoge()
```

Comment: 関数を再帰的に呼び出している箇所はどこでしょうか。最後の `hoge()` のインデントが間違っていたりしますか？

Comment: コードや欲しい結果を具体的に書くと、質問がより明確になると思います。

Comment: 再帰と勘違いしていたのでタイトル変更しました

Comment: コードや欲しい結果を具体的に書きました

Answer (score 0):

質問の内容が要領を得ないのですが，こういうことでしょうか．

```
def getHoge(p):
    return 処理

def hoge(res, results = []):
    if len(res) > 0:
        str = 処理
        results.append(str)
        hoge(getHoge(str), results)
    return results

hoge(getHoge("文字列"))
```

元のコードでは`res`が更新されないので，最初に`len(res) > 0`であれば無限ループになります．
また，変数`links`が何を指すのかも不明だったので，とりあえず`links == res`として考えました．

Comment: `result = []` のように、引数のデフォルト値としてリストのような可変データを指定すると問題になる事があります。
デフォルト値の初期化が関数の定義時に一度だけしか行なわれないからです。
この例ですと、`hoge` 関数の `results` 引数を指定しない呼び出しが二回以上あると「`result` が前回の値を覚えている」という事態になり、意図と異なる働きになると思います。
（手元で確認はしていないです。とりあえずのコメントという事でご容赦下さい）

Comment: 質問内容が分かりづらかったので、コードや欲しい結果を具体的に書きました

Comment: >  デフォルト値の初期化が関数の定義時に一度だけしか行なわれないからです

Comment: そういわれてみるとPythonはそんな動き方だった気がします…

Answer (score -1):

以下でどうでしょう

```
def getHoge(p):
    return 処理

def hoge():
    results = []
    res = getHoge("文字列")
    while len(res) > 0:
        str = 処理
        results.append(str)
        res = getHoge(str)
    return results

results = hoge()
```

Comment: 質問内容が分かりづらかったので、コードや欲しい結果を具体的に書きました